# VQE for Vibrational ground state energy

Tags: qiskit, vqe

I was reading this [article](https://pubs.aip.org/avs/aqs/article-abstract/5/1/013801/2879052/Description-of-reaction-and-vibrational-energetics?redirectedFrom=fulltext). In this article, they calculated the vibrational energy of CO2 and NH3 molecules using VQE, and I checked qiskit documentation for finding Vibrational energy using qiskit. Their code is not working.Anyone can help me how to get vibrational energy using Qiskits's VQE? I have attached the script along with the error. I got the logfile using gaussian software.

```
driver = GaussianForcesDriver(logfile="CO2-FREQ.LOG")
basis = HarmonicBasis([2, 2, 2, 2])
vibrational_problem = driver.run(basis=basis)
vibrational_problem.hamiltonian.truncation_order = 2
main_op, aux_ops = vibrational_problem.second_q_ops()
print(main_op)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[19], line 3
      1 driver = GaussianForcesDriver(logfile="CO2-FREQ.LOG")
      2 basis = HarmonicBasis([2, 2, 2, 2])
----> 3 vibrational_problem = driver.run(basis=basis)
      4 vibrational_problem.hamiltonian.truncation_order = 2
      5 main_op, aux_ops = vibrational_problem.second_q_ops()

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_nature/second_q/drivers/gaussiand/gaussian_forces_driver.py:153, in GaussianForcesDriver.run(self, basis)
    150 else:
    151     glr = GaussianLogDriver(jcf=self._jcf).run()
--> 153 watson = glr.get_watson_hamiltonian(normalize=self._normalize)
    155 problem = watson_to_problem(watson, basis=basis)
    156 return problem

File /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/qiskit_nature/second_q/drivers/gaussiand/gaussian_log_result.py:287, in GaussianLogResult.get_watson_hamiltonian(self, normalize)
    280     watson = WatsonHamiltonian(
    281         as_coo(quadratic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 2),
    282         as_coo(cubic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 3),
    283         as_coo(quartic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 4),
    284         -as_coo(quadratic_data, shape=(max_index,) * 2),
    285     )
    286 else:
--> 287     quadratic_numpy = np.zeros((max_index,) * 2)
    288     for coord, value in quadratic_data.items():
    289         quadratic_numpy[coord] = value

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

Comment: What is given in the quadratic/cubic/quartic force constant data in the log? It appears it couldn't find any indexes and thus it went with the default max_index of -1 if nothing is found for all three.